# Swift - didFinish navigation never called on load method

Tags: ios, swift, security, webview, wkwebview

I want to try the *hasOnlySecureContent* flag and I have this code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var text: UITextField!

var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 330, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height))
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
}

@IBAction func loadMixedContentPage(_ sender: Any) {

    // URL with mixed content
    let mixedContentURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")

    webView?.load(URLRequest(url: mixedContentURL!))

}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    // Detecting mixed content
    if !(webView.hasOnlySecureContent) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Security error", message: "Mixed content detected!", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true)

    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Information", message: "Content is not mixed!", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

However, the didFinish delegate is never called when clicked on *loadMixedContentPage* method that uses the *load* method.
However, if I use *loadHtml* instead of load, then the delegate is called.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Is it working if you add your web view to the view? self.view.addSubview(webView) in viewDidLoad

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: check logs i think something wrong with you http or https setting in plist file.

Comment: @AlexSmet you are right; indeed my issue was that I had a proxy set on my device, sorry.